# How to style a component to hide behind another component

Tags: react-native

I'm quite new to react native, I'm trying to understand how I can style two components to intercept with each other. Desirably have one component move behind the other component as if they were layers in Photoshop. I'd like to achieve this so that I can animate the styling of the hidden component to reveal it self on press of a touchable opacity. But i'm fine with the animation, I don't need any help there. I only need direction with how to correctly style a component to hide behind another component.

Here are the two components I'm working with, a text component contained inside a touchable opacity (the text box), and a date of publish text component. Both of which are contained inside a main view component.

```
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
    <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.dateText}>a few seconds ago</Text>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={styles.item}>this is some text input</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    item: {
        padding: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        borderColor: '#bbb',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    dateContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingHorizontal: 2,
        marginTop: 16,
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    },
    dateText: {
        color: '#adadad',
    },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the position:'absolute' and the zIndex in styles to have the layers for views.
The below style would place the dateContainer above the text component and in the corner of the text compoment. You can position the view using left,right,top or bottom.

```
 dateContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 2,
    top: 30,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    zIndex: 1000,
  },
```